# Shell script calling ''zsh -l && some_command'' never running some_command

Tags: shell, zsh

I have this basic shell script that I'm invoking via an alias:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /Users/tillman/t-root/dev/apps/actual-server && 
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login && 
yarn start
```

It moves directory, changes the arch but does not execute `yarn start`

If I break this up into two consecutive commands (executing the first and then the second within iterm via different aliases), it works:

alias = intel

```
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
```

alias = abudget

```
cd /Users/tillman/t-root/dev/apps/actual-server
yarn start
```

Output:

```
 ~ intel                                                                                                          ✔
 ~ abudget                                                                                                        ✔
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node app
Initializing Actual with user file dir: /Users/tillman/t-root/dev/apps/actual-server/user-files
Listening on 0.0.0.0:5006...
```

Why is it that the first option, with all commands in one script,  does not work?

Comment: I suspect it does work, but you're not letting it.  The `zsh` is running and giving you a shell. When you exit that shell (if you exit 0), then `yarn` will run.

Comment: Why `env /usr/bin/arch`? The point of `env`, if you aren't using it to add environment variables (as with `env var1=value1 var2=value2 program`), is to do a PATH lookup; but `/usr/bin/arch` being fully qualified, there's no lookup to be done.

Comment: BTW, think about using functions instead of aliases whenever your needs are even the slightest bit nontrivial; they give you far more flexibility, and the syntax makes common mistakes made defining aliases (like expanding variables at definition time rather than runtime, or failing to nest quotes circuit) moot. Also, aliases are disabled by default in scripts, but function syntax still works in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `yarn start` to be run *by* the copy of `zsh`, not run *after that copy of zsh exits* (which is what your code does now).

Consider using a heredoc or the `-c` argument to pass the code you want zsh to run on zsh's stdin:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ''|| exit'' prevents need to use && to connect to later commands
cd /Users/tillman/t-root/dev/apps/actual-server || exit

exec /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login -c 'exec yarn start'
```

The `exec`s are a performance enhancement, replacing the original shell with zsh, and then replacing the copy of zsh with a copy of `yarn`, instead of `fork()`ing subprocesses in which to run `zsh` and then `yarn`. (This also makes sending a signal to your script deliver that signal direct to `yarn`).

Comment: Legend, thanks very much! - for the code and the clear explanation 